# Facebook API send inbox messages (custom dialog)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, inbox

I'd trying to send private messages through Facebook API. I have already implement the FB Send Dialog through the JS SDK. The problem is that I'd like to create something customized, like the example below, took from www.joingrouper.com.

Does anyone know how this is done? Thanks!

[image: Grouper Facebook Inbox System]

Comment: No, sending private messages is possible via the Send dialog only¹ AFAIK. If it was possible via API, imagine how much spam that would create. (It is possible though, that joingrouper has access to a special API or extended privileges.) – ¹ unless maybe they are _abusing_ the Chat API for that.